# How to reduce the width of dropdown list of spinner in android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, width, spinner, reduce

In landscape mode, I have a spinner in my app. When I click the spinner, the dropdown list occupies the entire width of the screen. I want to reduce the width to the specific value. May I know how to do this ?

Senthil
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change your spinner layout width properties in the xml file to

```
android:layout_width="50dip" or android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I already given the layout_width as wrap_content only for spinner. Moreover I want to reduce the width of the dropdown list only and not the spinner itself.

Comment: ah, okay I have not done that myself but I had read somewhere you can use `dropDownSpinnerStyle` to change it..

Answer (score 1):

Change your spinner layout width properties in the xml file to

> android:dropDownWidth="50dp"